# VS Code, using python tkinter

Tags: python

I'm a rookie with Python, I like to use VScode, very useful. My question is about TKINTER. When I type "from tkinter import *" under the FROM statment it is underline.
from tkinter import * is the module is install properly or I did something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: When you hover over the underlined part, what is the error that is shown? That might help you to understand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

`from tkinter import *` is a perfectly acceptable way to import `tkinter` according to the [official Python documentation for tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: Thank you I re install vscode and python I don't have any underline now probs fix.